# Selecting one column among many returned by stored procedure in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which returns several number of columns. What I want to do is select only one column from the stored procedure returned data.

I tried with creating a temp table and inserting data from stored procedure to that temp table, but I'm getting errors.

What I want is something like this.

```
select p_name from Exec sp_getPatientData
```

where **sp_getPatientData** returns multiple columns.

can someone help me with it.

Comment: What error you are getting while using Temp table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem and solution also.

SP is

```
Create PROCEDURE spTest1
AS
BEGIN
if object_id('TEMPDB..#tbl1') is not null
drop table #tbl1
CREATE TABLE #tbl1 (column1 INT,column2 VARCHAR(100)    )
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = 'INSERT INTO #tbl1 
SELECT 111 AS column1,''2222'' AS column2
Union all
SELECT 221 AS column1,''2211'' AS column2'
insert into #tbl1
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql  

select column1,column2 from #tbl1
END
GO
```

and query is

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(column1 INT,column2 VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @tbl
    EXEC spTest1
SELECT column1 FROM @tbl
```

Error generated

```
Msg 8164, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spTest1, Line 31
An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.
```

Solution:
   You cannot use insert when there is nested EXEC. i just removed the string query from store procedure and used direct select query. Problem was solved.

Answer (score 3):

If you have this store procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spTest
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT 1 AS column1,'2' AS column2
END
GO
```

Then you could do this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(column1 INT,column2 VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @tbl
    EXEC spTest

SELECT column1 FROM @tbl
```

**Update:**
You have a problem in the syntax:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
DECLARE tabl1 TABLE (Session_n int, patient_n int, initialName varchar(50), 
                     nodeValue varchar(50), diagCode varchar(50)); 
INSERT INTO tbl1 
EXEC SP_PATIENTALERTS 
SELECT PATIENT_N FROM tbl1 WHERE PATIENT_N = 12345
```

this part:

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 
EXEC SP_PATIENTALERTS 
SELECT PATIENT_N FROM tbl1 WHERE PATIENT_N = 12345
```

I think. Should be like this:

```
INSERT INTO tabl1 
EXEC SP_PATIENTALERTS 
SELECT PATIENT_N FROM tabl1 WHERE PATIENT_N = 12345
```

Comment: but in my case it gives following error **"An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested."**

Comment: @Fazal : Does this short demo work for you? Can you show the exact code you are running?

Comment: SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE tabl1 TABLE (Session_n int, patient_n int, initialName varchar(50), nodeValue varchar(50), diagCode varchar(50));

INSERT INTO tbl1
EXEC SP_PATIENTALERTS 

SELECT PATIENT_N
FROM tbl1
WHERE PATIENT_N = 12345